# 405 (Method Not Allowed) - Laravel and Vue.Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good afternoon everyone, I'm trying to implement a notification system with the possibility to mark this notification with a like.

I am using laravel 7 for the back end and vuejs for the front end.

The code works correctly on localhost, but when I deploy to Heroku it stops working and to give me the message below.

```
http://springalert.herokuapp.com/api/like 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405
at createError (app.js:5347)
at settle (app.js:5608)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:4816)
```

Someone with any tips for the subject, I researched about it and I know that we have to configure CORS but for this version of laravel it supposedly would no longer be necessary.

follow the code, thank you for your help.

ROUTE

```
Route::post('/api/like/', 'NotificationController@api_like');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function api_like(Request $request) {
  $like = new Like;
  $like->notification_id = $request->id;
  $like->user_id = auth()->id();
  $like->save();
}
```

VUEJS

```
<b-card-text class="text-right" v-if="Object.keys(notification.like).length == 0">
   <a @click="makelike('success', 'Informação', notification.id)" class="a"><i class="fas fa thumbs-up"></i></a>
</b-card-text>
```

```
      makelike(variant = null, title, notification_id) {
        this.id = notification_id
        axios.post('api/like/',{ id:this.id })
                    .then((response) => {
                      this.set_notifications()
                      this.$bvToast.toast('Obrigado pela tua visualização', {
                        title: title,
                        variant: variant,
                        solid: true
                      })
                    })
      },
```

Comment: POST requests need csrf unless you removed it.

Comment: is your route in the web.php file or in the api.php file?

Comment: Most likely, the URL is getting rewritten to GET method. You might have to check the server configuration. Can you check that once?

Comment: /api is normally prefixed in the routes/api.php file,  so you don't need /api in the route (if it's in this file)  in api.php Route::post('/like/', 'NotificationController@api_like');  will resolve at /api/like

Comment: @Cameron in web.php

Comment: If i change to api.php
```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/like', 'NotificationController@api_like');
```
then the error change to The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Your api seems to be fine, the problem is that your front end is sending a get request instead of a post request

Comment: Try `axios.post('/api/like/',` prepend the route with **/**

Comment: As @VinayakSarawagi said, check your server config. This has happened to me before. I posted to a http protocol and then https was enforced so the POST method was rewritten to a GET method.

Comment: Any idea how I can make this change in Heroku

Comment: after some digging , you can only post to heroku when using ssl/https https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441591/post-request-being-received-as-get-request-on-heroku

Comment: I think maybe because of one forward slash assume it to be a get route

Answer (score 0):

As user Mihai pointed out, you need to chain your POST request after a get request to csrf.

Here's how it looks like with Laravel Sanctum:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const baseUrl = 'http://yourdomain.com'
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseUrl,
  withCredentials: true
})
const payload = {}

api().get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => {
  return api().post('api/like', payload).then(resp => {
     // Do stuff with resp
  })
})
```