# Where is my fault? PUT method not allowed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

Help me please to find my fault?

my data return
[image]

my update method
[image]

and then this my edit

```
editHandler(item) {
      this.inputType = "Ubah";
      this.editId = item.id_profile;
      this.form.noinduk = item.noinduk;
      this.form.tanggal = item.tanggal;
      this.form.tempat = item.tempat;
      this.form.jeniskelamin = item.jeniskelamin;
      this.form.asalsekolah = item.asalsekolah;
      this.form.tahun = item.tahun;
    },
```

my problem
[image]

my route/api
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd9eU.png)

Comment: show ``routes/web.php`` codes

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410852/405-method-not-allowed-laravel-and-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `id` as parameter. `editId` should have value. While it is empty, your route trying to access:

```
Route::get('Profile',  'Api\ProfileController@index');
```

route. And as error said it is not allowed. Because it supports only get method. Url should look like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Profile/357
```

357 may be any number that represents id