# django-rest-framework - POST Request returns "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have set up django-rest-auth as per the installation tutorial, yet I am not able to use the login API endpoint. When I send a POST request with the correct information, I receive a 405 status error in response with "Method "GET" not allowed."

However, when I navigate to the actual URL and POST it from the online form, it works fine and returns a token.

Help?!

Example with Postman:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ISSv.png

Example with Axios:

```
axios.post('http://----.com/api/accounts/login/', data: {'username': ---, 'password': ---})
.then(function (response) {console.log(response);})
.catch(function (response) {console.log(response);})
```

UPDATE:

This seems to be an issue with possibly Heroku or Gunicorn? The website is deployed on Heroku using Gunicorn, but all POST Requests are being received as GET requests.

Comment: How are you sending the request that is failing?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid I've sent the request using Postman and using Axios (from React Native. Both return status code 405.

Comment: The problem is how you are sending the request with Postman / Axios, and not with DRF because clearly its working (as you said yourself) if you use the browser. So unless you edit the question and add the code example that's not working, not sure how to help you here.

Comment: Hi Burhan, I have added my Axios request code above. Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For anyone coming across this strange phenomenon of a POST request turning into a GET request mysteriously...

I'm using Django + DRF on Heroku. The problem was so simple it made me want to laugh and cry at the same time.

Heroku redirects requests to http://example.com to http://www.example.com, and this redirection involves a GET request. As a result, the POST request is received as a GET request without any of the headers or body that was initially present.

All of that work and frustration just for a missing 'www'. Hope this helps somebody in the future!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688973/8407856

Comment: This helped me!

Comment: Thank you! The redirect in django routing itself caused me the issue. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: A god among men. Thank you!

Comment: I had a trailing slash missing 

Comment: Mine was redirecting http to https. Including https in the link solved the problem

Comment: If you are having this problem on postman - dont forget to have a / at the end of your URL :|

Comment: @Ariel thanks a lot! I was also missing a trailing slash when calling a Django api via node backend server (node-fetch)

Comment: For me , after setting up SSL , I left 1 url as http in my env and it creating the issue. After changing http to https , it worked for me 
Thanks for your answer a

Answer (score 3):

You might also see this error if you don't provide a trailing `/` on the end of your URL when building the request. For example, Django will give a 405 error for this request:

```
import requests

response = requests.post(
    url='https://myapi.com/api/endpoint',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Token {authentication_token}'},
    data=data,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I ignore `https://` prefix, so Nginx was redirecting `backend.foo.com` to `https://backend.foo.com`, and within this, method POST was changing to GET, so I just added `https://` prefix and it worked