# Django's SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT and Heroku causes redirected Rest Framework POST requests to become GET requests

Tags: django, rest, heroku, django-rest-framework

I have Django project hosted on Heroku

There's a web-application and a Django REST API.

I'm using `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` and `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` to redirect all *http* traffic to *https*.

The web-application is happy. If I try to use a *http* link, it redirects to *https*, and I can use forms, etc.

For the Django REST API, if I try a *http* link and a *POST* request, it redirects successfully to *https* but the method becomes a *GET* and the API requests the request (because it is meant to be a *POST*).

I do not know if this is expected behaviour, or if this is a Heroku specific thing. If it's expected for redirects, I'd appreciate to understand why (from a technical point).

And or if there is a solution.

Comment: you will find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343523/django-rest-framework-post-request-returns-method-get-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks so much! Your searching skills are much better than mine. So the solution is to recognize `www` in our URL definitions as well?

Comment: Lol thank you, just keep practice searching and you will get there:) yes, that way there is no redirection.