# Double request logged from node request to Django endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I'm trying to send a POST request to a django endpoint. It fails due to a 405. Inspecting the logs, it appears to receive the POST request, but then immediately followed by a GET request and returns a 405 as this is a POST only endpoint.

I've stripped the fetching code back to the following js script:

```js
const fetchData = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/user", {
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      test: "test",
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    const text = await response.text();
    console.log("error", response, text);
  }
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log("json", json);
};

fetchData();
```

[image]

It doesn't seem to matter what endpoint, or what method I send, it always logs a double request. What's also interesting, is if I send a PUT request, it logs a double PUT request, same for GET or even OPTIONS. However, for all POST requests, the second requests is always a GET. Again, it doesn't matter what endpoint I hit! I'm stumped

I'm a JS dev, but I have access to the Django code if it would help to post the urls.py or any of the views from there?

Comment: Can you share how the fetchData method is being called also might be helpful if you can show the django code related to it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the fix was trivially simple and i'm still kicking myself a week later.
This "related question" helped me find the answer - [django-rest-framework - POST Request returns "Method \"GET\" not allowed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343523/django-rest-framework-post-request-returns-method-get-not-allowed?rq=2)

**ANSWER**
I needed to append a `/` on the end of my urls. The server was performing a redirect for urls missing the `/` on the end and loosing some headers in the process.